# Gradient and hessian of $\log(x^TAx)$

Tags: matrix-calculus

I am working on a optimization problem which involves the gradient and hessian of $\log(x^TAx)$, where $x$ is an unknown vector and $A$ is a positive definite matrix. How can I derive them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define a quadratic form and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 \alpha &= x^TAx \cr
d\alpha &= 2(Ax)^T dx \cr
}$$
The objective function is the log of the preceeding, so its differential and gradient are easy to calculate.
$$\eqalign{
\lambda &= \log\alpha \cr
d\lambda
 &= \alpha^{-1}d\alpha \cr
 &= 2\alpha^{-1}(Ax)^T dx \cr
g = \frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial x} &= 2\alpha^{-1}Ax \cr
}$$
Now let's calculate the differential of $g$ and thence the hessian. 
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= 2\alpha^{-1}A\,dx - 2Ax\,\,\alpha^{-2}\,d\alpha \cr
 &= 2\alpha^{-1}A\,dx - 4\alpha^{-2}Ax(Ax)^T\,dx \cr
H = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
 &= 2\alpha^{-1}A - 4\alpha^{-2}Ax(Ax)^T \cr
 &= 2\alpha^{-1}A - gg^T \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. BTW, A is not necessarily symmetric. Your solution is enough for me to derive the final answer.